# (Why) is this instantiation of a template class with a temporary/anonymous object a vexing parse?

Tags: c++, most-vexing-parse

This code:

```
// main.cpp

template< typename T >
class Owner {
public:
  Owner( const T& t )
    : t_( t ) {}

  void func() { }

private:
  T t_;
};

class Foo {
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
  Owner<Foo> owner( Foo() );

  owner.func();

  return 0;
}
```

generates this error:

```
$ g++ --version && g++ -g ./main.cpp
g++ (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

./main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
./main.cpp:22:9: error: request for member ‘func’ in ‘owner’, which is of non-class type ‘Owner<Foo>(Foo (*)())’
   owner.func();
         ^~~~
```

**Question:** Is this a compile error because the definition of `owner` is a vexing parse, and if so, why?
I'm trying to tease apart how the compiler might interpret the definition of `owner` as anything other than a variable declaration...I can see how it might think "*owner is a function that returns an instance of `Owner<Foo>`*" but I don't see why that wouldn't be ruled out by the temporary/anonymous variable in the parentheses - how could that be confused with an argument list?

**Question:** Is there a workaround that allows me to instantiate a `Owner<Foo>` instance with a temporary/anonymous variable? I.e. instantiating a `Owner<Foo>` with a temporary *named* `Foo` instance works around this compiler problem, but I'd like to avoid that. I.e. the following works, but I'd like to avoid creating named `Foo` instances:

```
// main.cpp

template< typename T >
class Owner {
public:
  Owner( const T& t )
    : t_( t ) {}

  void func() { }

private:
  T t_;
};

class Foo {
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
  Foo tmp;
  Owner<Foo> owner( tmp );

  owner.func();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This declaration:

```
Owner<Foo> owner( Foo() );
```

is indeed a vexing parse. It declares `owner` as a function that returns an `Owner<Foo>`, and which has a single parameter. That single parameter `Foo()` is itself interpreted as a function that returns a `Foo` and has no parameters.

The simplest way to fix this is by using braces instead of parentheses:

```
Owner<Foo> owner{ Foo{} };
```

and now there's no ambiguity, and no need for any named variables of type `Foo`.